# Shared Preferences error in Flutter - iOS on Mac

Tags: ios, sharedpreferences, flutter

I'm trying to run Flutter app on iOS on Mac. When I'm trying to build project, it gives me this error:

> Xcode's output:
>       ↳
>       === BUILD TARGET shared_preferences OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>       In file included from /Users/(username)/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.2.4/ios/Classes/SharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
>       /Users/(username)/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.2.4/ios/Classes/SharedPreferencesPlugin.h:1:9:
>   fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
>       #import 
>       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       1 error generated.
>       Could not build the application for the simulator.

I've tried to build it from different Flutter channels, no change.

Any idea what is wrong?

EDIT: 
flutter version 0.2.8
pod version 1.5.0

Comment: What flutter version are you using? `flutter --version`. Also the output of `pod --version` would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16036#issuecomment-380712094 provides instructions that seemed to have worked for others

> Can I ask you to try the following:
>
> - make sure you have Cocoapods 1.5.0 installed (`pod --version` should say
>     `1.5.0`)
> - change any dependencies you have on the `firebase_xxx`, `google_sign_in`, or `cloud_firestore` plugins to the newest versions
>     (look for changelog entries referring to Cocoapods 1.5.0)
> - change your
>     `ios/Podfile` to the newest version on Flutter master branch
>     (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/cocoapods)
> - delete `ios/Podfile.lock` and `ios/Pods` switch to Flutter master branch
> - `flutter clean ; flutter run`

Comment: This fixed my flutter.h not found problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to include the audioplayer package

> ... audioplayer-0.4.0/ios/Classes/AudioplayerPlugin.h:1:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found).

I thought I was up-to-date, but after I did a Flutter upgrade and then deleted Podfile, Podfile.lock and the Pods folder from my ios directory under my project (and ran flutter clean), I was finally able to build and launch to iOS. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/16273

I'm using Xcode 9.3 and Cocoapods 1.5.0.

Flutter shows version 0.3.1 after upgrading.